# .NET Core React Redux template JS 404 issue on deploy

Tags: .net, .net-core, react-redux

New to .Net Core and have started a new project built off the .NET Core React Redux template.  The app runs fine through VS2017.
I have built a folder publish (debug configuration) through VS2017.  The publish seems to go smoothly.  When hitting the published site I get 404s for my js and css files.

[Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qKqA.png)

Index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><base href="/"/
        ><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <title>nSITE Explorer</title>
        <link href="/static/css/main.872a5e7a.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/main-cssmodules.7f40876c.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.735c95d1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do see the word "Test" that was thrown into the HTML.

Here is part of the file structure on the server:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOACl.png)

If I change the src attribute in the html to this:

```
<body>
    Test
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="explorer2/ClientApp/build/static/js/main.735c95d1.js"></script>
</body>
```

And refresh the site I get a 200.
[result with altered index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5o3N.png)

But the response from that 200 is...html?
[response from 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XinDh.png)

In case it helps, here is my Startup.cs.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using Windsor.Site.Code;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using System.Reflection;
using Windsor.Site.Controllers;
using System.IO;

namespace Windsor.Site
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Startup));
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
            // If we want to pull these from the db we can so an ado call right here
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IAppSettingsRepository, AppSettingsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ILayerRepository, LayerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IProfileRepository, ProfileRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISiteRepository, SiteRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "nSite Explorer API",
                    Description = "List of API for nSite Explorer"
                });
                c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
                c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            });

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Should be the first item in Configure so we can catch exceptions from the other items
            app.UseExceptionHandler(
                 options =>
                 {
                     options.Run(
                         async context =>
                                {
                                    var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                                    // Log the error
                                    log.Error("An unhandled exception occurred.");
                                    log.Error("Request Path : " + context.Request.Path);
                                    log.Error("Exception Message : " + ex.Error.Message);
                                    if (ex.Error.InnerException != null)
                                    {
                                        log.Error("Inner Exception : " + ex.Error.InnerException.Message);
                                    }
                                    log.Error("Exception Stack Trace : " + ex.Error.StackTrace);

                                    // Return the error to the client
                                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

                                    if (ex != null)
                                    {
                                        var err = $"<h1>Error: {ex.Error.Message}</h1>";
                                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(err).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                    }
                                }
                    );
                 });

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();
            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "nSite Explorer API V1");
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            //app.UseIdentity();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
        private string GetXmlCommentsPath()
        {
            var commentsFileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml";
            return System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, commentsFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on why this is happening?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? We're experiencing it at the moment. It seems to be an issue with UseReactDevelopmentServer. With that line commented out all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but after recently running into this issue, I managed to trace it down. There is now an open issue for the problem here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24338